# Fetching data from APRS-IS.net

Tags: aprs

I would like to fetch the data transmitted by a specific radio station from [APRS-IS.net servers](http://www.aprs-is.net/Connecting.aspx). I've read the documentation on their site and it is not clear how you would do it, if you are fetching the data instead of transmitting it. It is mentioned to use a callsign and password, but I'm not sure where to get them from.

Comment: Hello Daniela, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com! The callsign would be the amateur radio callsign assigned to you by the FCC (I'm assuming you are in the USA?). It sounds like you don't have a callsign yet (mine is W0BTU). I am not familiar with APRS, so hopefully someone more knowledgeable than I will come along here and help you.

Comment: Thank you Mike. From another forum, I was told use the callsign `N0CALL' and a passcode of -1.

Comment: Okay ... was the callsign N**0**CALL (zero), or N**O**CALL (capital letter O)? Perhaps that is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I am using firenet.aprs2.net and euro.aprs2.net for APRS-IS data.
If you need to fetch packets you have to connect to a server on a specific port.
Usually port 14580 is the one to use. Once a connection is established you are
supposed to authorize yourself using your callsign and password. Password is
a hash algorithm based on your callsign.
Here is an example of how to request packets from a APRS-IS server:

```
user {your_callsign} pass {password_hash} vers {your_software_name} filter r/{latitude}/{longitude}/{range}\n
```

for example: your GPS location is 50.000N by 20.000E and you want to request packets within 200km range, use the following packet filter:

```
... filter /r/50.000/20.000/200
```

Please bear in mind that you need to add LF ("\n") char to the end of your request.
If you need more details please contact me via my website http://www.so6agj.pl

73